# Does GKE support container checkpoints

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, containerd

Does Google Kubernetes Engine support creating a checkpoint for a container running on a given host. This issue [`kubernetes #3949`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/3949) says that kubernetes is not going to support it anytime soon. But is it possible to do it from the host where the containers are running.

GKE allows a maintainer to ssh on the compute for **troubleshooting**. The host has a utility [`ctr`](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/tree/main/cmd/ctr) to interact with the containerd socket (which is the default container engine). The `ctr` utility does have options to perform a checkpoint in 2 different ways

```
user@gke-cluster-1-default-pool-ef0e509f-p9lw ~ $ ctr containers checkpoint <container_id> test2
ctr: image "test2": already exists
user@gke-cluster-1-default-pool-ef0e509f-p9lw ~ $ ctr containers checkpoint <container_id> test3
user@gke-cluster-1-default-pool-ef0e509f-p9lw ~ $ echo $?
0
```

The utility performs a check for an already existing checkpoint and does not throw out an error, but during a checkpoint we get this error from containerd,

```
Aug 15 20:29:11 gke-cluster-1-default-pool-ef0e509f-p9lw containerd[1441]: time="2021-08-15T20:29:11.892718841Z" level=info msg="ImageCreate event &ImageCreate{Name:test2,Labels:map[string]string{},XXX_unrecognized:[],}"
Aug 15 20:29:11 gke-cluster-1-default-pool-ef0e509f-p9lw containerd[1441]: time="2021-08-15T20:29:11.893607606Z" level=error msg="Failed to handle event &ImageCreate{Name:test2,Labels:map[string]string{},XXX_unrecognized:[],} for test2" error="get image id: unexpected media type application/vnd
.containerd.container.checkpoint.runtime.options+proto for sha256:d8183a03f8f3429623e6aa55d13c70d1bfc282fe5c3d6562180fdc55c7614589: not found"
```

The other way just says [`criu`](https://criu.org/Main_Page) is not present in the `PATH` which was verified as checkpoints usually works using the `criu` utility.

Is the feature supported (perhaps a configuration that needs to be enabled) or not and how to verify it.

Comment: If the feature is not yet supported in kubernetes or still have [bugs to be fixed](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/97689), it will be the same with GKE. Though depending on your use case, you may want to consider checking [volume snapshots](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/volume-snapshots) as a workaround. This [article](https://github.com/checkpoint-restore/criu/issues/1230) may also help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Alex. I had read about complications of dumping a container using criu (because of namespacing issues, it's not very straight forward). For that I was trying to use the ctr utility for containerd. The docker runtime on GKE requires enabling the experimental feature which I didn't try. The ctr utility has a checkpoint command but doesn't seem to do anything. I had also come across Adrian's PR about checkpointing support in the CRI spec. :) So before doing any more digging, I wanted to see if anyone had already played with it.